# Format to xml view in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-view

I would like to give this structure to new fields that I add to this (inherited) view.

[image: xml view]

This is the `xml` code that I am using:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>

  <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="fleet_vehicule_l10n_new_form"
            model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.l10n.new.form</field>
            <field name="model">fleet.vehicle</field>
            <field name="inherit_id"
                ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_view_form" />
            <field name="arch"
                type="xml">

                <field name="model_id"
                    position="after">
                    <group >
                        <field name="vehiculo_sat" />
                    </group>
                </field>

                <field name="description"
                    position="after">

                    <group string="MX EDI group">

                        <field name="transport_permit_no" />
                        <field name="transport_insurer" />
                        <field name="transport_insurance_policy" />
                        <field name="transport_perm_sct" />

                        <field name="vehicle_model" />
                        <field name="vehicle_config" />
                        <field name="vehicle_licence" />
                        <field name="trailer_ids" />
                        <field name="figure_ids" />
                    </group>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

How can I achieve this? I understand that odoo uses `bootstrap`, but I don't know how to apply the classes in the `xml` of an inherited view.

## Edit

I try this, but still not working:

```html
<field name="description" position="after">



  <!-- <field name="vehicle_licence" />
                        <field name="vehicle_model" /> -->
  <group>

    <field name="transport_permit_no" />
    <field name="transport_insurer" />
    <field name="transport_insurance_policy" />
    <field name="transport_perm_sct" />
  </group>

  <field name="vehicle_config" />
  <group>
    <field name="trailer_ids" />
  </group>
  <group>
    <field name="figure_ids" />
  </group>
</field>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To have two groups, one on the left and the other on the right, add two groups inside a group

Comment: I try, but its not working. Check my edit.

Comment: The description filed is inside a group, the result will be different from what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `description` filed is inside a group, so adding two groups inside a group won't work like in the picture above.

You can add the group to `sheet` like following:

```
<xpath expr="//sheet" position="inside">
    <group>
        <group string="MX EDI group">
            <field name="transport_permit_no"/>
            <field name="transport_insurer"/>
            <field name="transport_insurance_policy"/>
            <field name="transport_perm_sct"/>
            <field name="vehicle_model"/>
            <field name="vehicle_config"/>
            <field name="vehicle_licence"/>
        </group>
         <group string="Second Group">
             
         </group>
     </group>
     <group>
         <field name="trailer_ids"/>
         <field name="figure_ids"/>
     </group>
 </xpath>
```

The default fleet vehicle form added six groups inside a group, so you can append the two groups inside that group

***Example:***

```
<xpath expr="//sheet/group" position="inside">
    <group string="MX EDI group">
        <field name="transport_permit_no"/>
        <field name="transport_insurer"/>
        <field name="transport_insurance_policy"/>
        <field name="transport_perm_sct"/>
        <field name="vehicle_model"/>
        <field name="vehicle_config"/>
        <field name="vehicle_licence"/>
    </group>
    <group string="Second Group">
        
    </group>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//sheet/group" position="after">
    <group>
        <field name="trailer_ids"/>
        <field name="figure_ids"/>
    </group>
</xpath>
```

The default `col` attribute value for group is `2`